# Connection Timeout for EC2 Instance Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I have an ec2 instance running and I want to connect to the Mongodb database.

I have done the following steps but still i am getting the connection timeout error.

1. Add 0.0.0.0 to the bindIp
2. Add 27017 to ufw
3. Allow the inbound rule from the Security.
4. Restart the mongodb

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your security group rules for that EC2 instance?

Comment: Your question lacks clearity. From where are you trying to connect? From which security group have you allowed inbound rule? Is mongodb running(show output of `netstat -ntlp`)?